# Eclipse Custom Marker View

Tags: eclipse-pde, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create a customized marker view. In this view I want to restrict/filter the resources to selected project only. This project name will be supplied dynamically.

For e.g, in the context menu from project explorer, the user will be given option to open the Custom Marker View.

If the user chooses the Custom Marker View from project1, the view should show only the markers of the project1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar. At first define a View in your plugin.xml the corresponding class must extend MarkerSupportView. Something like this:

```
public class MarkerView extends MarkerSupportView {

public MarkerView() {
    super("com.example.markerEventContentGenerator"); //$NON-NLS-1$

}
}
```

Then you need to define the columns in your new view and what kind of markers have to be shown. Here is an example from plugin.xml.

```
 <extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerSupport">
<markerContentGenerator
      id="com.example.markerEventContentGenerator"
      name="Custom Marker View">
    <markerTypeReference 
     id="com.example.myMarker"/>
</markerContentGenerator>
<markerField
      class="com.example.fields.NameMarkerField"
      id="com.example.field.name"
      name="Name">
</markerField>
</extension>
```

The NameMarkerField class must extend MarkerField. Another dummy example:

```
public class AnnotationNameMarkerField extends MarkerField {

public AnnotationNameMarkerField() {
    super();
}

@Override
public String getValue(final MarkerItem item) {
    return "Dummy Name";
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 *
 * @see
 * org.eclipse.ui.views.markers.MarkerField#getDefaultColumnWidth(org.eclipse
 * .swt.widgets.Control)
 */
@Override
public int getDefaultColumnWidth(final Control control) {
    return 400;
}
}
```

Now you have to decide how to create your project specific markers with id="com.example.myMarker".

Comment: Thanks. I just do not get where should I define the `MarkerView`? When is it created?

Comment: MarkerView is a normal view. You need to create it in a plugin and register it in plugin.xml  as extension point: org.eclipse.ui.view. Then you will be able to see the View over the Show View Dialog (Window --> Show View --> Other View...)

Comment: And what should be the ID of `<markerField`? [I see](http://www.eclipse-tips.com/how-to-guides/14-creating-a-custom-marker-view) that there are standard IDs like id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.resourceField". Which one should I choose? They also say that I must use `markerFieldReference` isntead of `markerFieldReference` and do it inside the `markerContentGenerator` rather than sibling to it.

Comment: As far as I remember the resourceField will be shown in the Problems View. Thats why I use custom id. You need to try it out. Please let me know if that's the case or not..

Comment: Ok, I see now how things are connected. The custom "org.eclipse.ui.views" extenstion point refers to your class and you can instantiate it opening View > Others. The name of the view is assigned in name attribute of the ext point. Java constructor of the view refers to the markerContentGenerator.id, specified in the "org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerSupport" ext point. This marker support customizes the columns of the view. The `markerTypeReference` within the markerContentGenerator must match one of the `markerField`. I have achieved this by having identical IDs.

Comment: I had to breakpoint the debugger in ExtendedMarkersView.init() and MarkerContentGenerator.restoreState() to force memento = null manually. Otherwise, some oudated columns were represented in my I could go on and see my columns. I have no idea how to clean the settings properly. Also, I would like to know how to fill the view with my markers

Comment: Ok, you can show the view by `page.showView("view id")`. This view ID corresponds to one specified in plugin.xml in `<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">`. You can add the markers by `IMarker marker = aResource.createMarker("marker type id"); marker.setAttribute("your column id", value);`. The marker type is the one specified in the xml markerContentGenerator section, `<markerTypeReference id="marker type id"/>`. The typical problem with Eclipse is that the docs are too fragmentary. It takes time to tie the pieces together.